# TableRow style changing by condition

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

There are two tables:

```
@FXML
TableView<FrameGroupIntersections> tvOldGroups;
@FXML
TableView<FrameGroupIntersections> tvNewGroups;
```

[image]

These are linked in the class:

```
public class FrameGroupIntersections {

    private FrameGroup group;

    private ObservableMap<FrameGroupIntersections,IntTypeInfoWrapper> intersections;

    private BooleanProperty hasErr;

    FrameGroupIntersections (FrameGroup group, Map<FrameGroupIntersections,IntTypeInfoWrapper> intersections){
        this.group = group;
        hasErr = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        setIntersections(intersections);
    }

    FrameGroupIntersections(FrameGroup group){
        this(group,null);
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

i.e. `FrameGroupIntersections` from left table has link for `FrameGroupIntersections` from right table in `intersections` map. Same happens the other way around.

When controller initialize, i recieve two ObservableList as "old" and "new".

```
class Controller {
    //FXML nodes
    //Lists of intersections
    ObservableList<FrameGroupIntersections> oFgInt;
    ObservableList<FrameGroupIntersections> nFgInt;

    public void init(MergeReportDataWrapper dataWrapper){
        this.oFgInt = dataWrapper.getoFgInt();
        this.nFgInt = dataWrapper.getnFgInt();
        //Data binding
    }
}
```

All intersections in that lists are linked.

It is necessary that when selected some of `FrameGroupIntersections` in both tables, linked `FrameGroupIntersections` rows from other table changing own background. Tell me please how this can be done?

Comment: I fail to see the connection in the `FrameGroupIntersections` class. Furthermore there's a method mitting and the type of `intersections` will surely cause problems, if `intersections` should be updated with data from other items.

Comment: @fabian when its using by controller, in `intersections` data can only be removed. I can't understand you about "fail to see the connection". By "link", i mean that in `intersections` has all "intersected" FrameGroups with intersection type.

Comment: Could you add some code to the question to demonstrate how to determine, if selecting `FrameGroupIntersections a` in the first table would mean `FrameGroupIntersections b` in the second table would need to be highlighted. Right now the `intersections` field only seems to be some `Map` mapping from `FrameGroupIntersections` to some type that is not described in the question...

Comment: @fabian. I described in the question, how its must work. I have 2 lists with `FrameGroupIntersections` as "old" and "new". Connections exist only between "old" and "new" intersections. Because its may be more than one intersections at current FrameGroup, i use Map, when key is intersected `FrameGroupIntersections` object, and value is type of this interception.

Comment: I agree that this is really unclear. Each `FrameGroupIntersections` instance has its *own map* from `FrameGroupIntersections` to some other object (no idea what the role of that object is)? Isn't there a more standard way to model your data that others can understand?

Comment: @James_D sorry, but i don't know about "more standard way", because its standard for me. If you have some alternative ways, please tell me about them. I will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure how you determine if an item needs to be selected in the other `TableView`, so I created some example simply using `Map`s to mapping from the item to the list of objects to select from the other table.

`Item<T>` is just a class with a `value` property wrapping objects of type `T` here:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // create data
    ObservableList<Item<String>> data1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Item("A"),
            new Item("B"),
            new Item("C"),
            new Item("D")
    );
    ObservableList<Item<String>> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Item("A"),
            new Item("B"),
            new Item("C"),
            new Item("D")
    );

    // create tableview & columns
    TableView<Item<String>> table1 = new TableView<>(data1);
    TableView<Item<String>> table2 = new TableView<>(data2);

    TableColumn<Item<String>, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>();
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("value"));

    TableColumn<Item<String>, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>();
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("value"));

    table1.getColumns().add(column1);
    table2.getColumns().add(column2);

    // create maps mapping values to values to select in the other table,
    // should a item be selected
    Map<Item<String>, List<Item<String>>> selection1To2 = new HashMap<>();
    selection1To2.put(data1.get(0), Arrays.asList(data2.get(0), data2.get(1)));
    selection1To2.put(data1.get(2), Arrays.asList(data2.get(1), data2.get(2)));

    Map<Item<String>, List<Item<String>>> selection2To1 = new HashMap<>();
    selection2To1.put(data2.get(1), Arrays.asList(data1.get(2), data1.get(3)));
    selection2To1.put(data2.get(3), Arrays.asList(data1.get(0), data1.get(1), data1.get(2), data1.get(3)));

    // sets of items to select depending on table selections
    ObservableSet<Item<String>> otherSelections1 = connect(table2, selection2To1);
    ObservableSet<Item<String>> otherSelections2 = connect(table1, selection1To2);

    // assign row factories for assigning pseudoclasses
    table1.setRowFactory(new RowFactory(otherSelections1));
    table2.setRowFactory(new RowFactory(otherSelections2));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(10, table1, table2));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static <T> ObservableSet<T> connect(TableView<T> table, Map<T, List<T>> map) {
    ObservableSet<T> result = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());

    // keep set elements the union of the list elements for the items selected in the table
    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((Observable o) -> {
        result.clear();
        for (T item : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            List<T> itemsToAdd = map.get(item);
            if (itemsToAdd != null) {
                result.addAll(itemsToAdd);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

private static final PseudoClass OTHER_SELECTED = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("other-selected");

private static class RowFactory implements Callback<TableView<Item<String>>, TableRow<Item<String>>> {

    private final ObservableSet<Item<String>> selected;

    public RowFactory(ObservableSet<Item<String>> selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<Item<String>> call(TableView<Item<String>> param) {
        // rows contain pseudoclass depending on other selection
        return new TableRow<Item<String>>() {

            {
                selected.addListener((Observable o) -> updateOtherSelected());
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Item<String> item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                updateOtherSelected();
            }

            private void updateOtherSelected() {
                pseudoClassStateChanged(OTHER_SELECTED, selected.contains(getItem()));
            }

        };
    }

}
```

#### style.css

```css
.table-row-cell:other-selected {
    -fx-background: orange;
}

.table-row-cell:other-selected:selected {
    -fx-background: purple;
}
```